# Prove the equality always not holds

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives

$f(x)=ae^x+x^2-bx$

if $x_0$ does not equal to $m$, $a$ does not equal to $0$, both of $a$ and $b$ are constant.

Show that, there must not be $x_0 \in R$ to let the equality holds where $m$ is a constant.

The equality: $\frac{f(x_0)-f(m)}{x_0-m}=f'(\frac{x_0+m}{2})$

$f'(\frac{x_0+m}{2})=ae^{\frac{x_0+m}{2}}+x_0+m-b$

I try to connect the equality to the MVT but it tells nothing.

Now the question narrows down to solve the equation $\frac{e^x-e^m}{x-m}=e^{\frac{x+m}{2}}$

If I divided $e^m$ to both sides, the question turns into $e^{x-m}-1=(x-m)e^{\frac{x-m}{2}}$ has solution other than $x=m$.

Comment: Have you tried directly computing the derivative and plugging in $(x_0+m)/2$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Does it tell anything? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Hm it's not immediately straightforward, but I think the crux is seeing that as $x_0\to m$ we have equality.

Comment: I try to solve it directly but it is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On simplifying, the equality becomes 
$$\frac{e^{x_0} - e^m}{x_0 - m} = e^\frac{x_0 + m}{2}$$
or $$e^\frac{x_0 - m}{2} - e^\frac{m-x_0}{2} = x_0 - m$$

Let $e^\frac{x_0 - m}{2} = t$. Then, we have $$t - \frac{1}{t} = 2\ln t$$
Graphically, we can easily see that the only solution to this is $t = 1$ i.e. $x_0 = m$. But, this is not possible, as the equality is not defined for $x_0 = m$.

Hence, this has no solution.